# What is a gentler word than "suspended" or "closed"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, connotation, past-participles

What word can show that an action is redeemable? Is there a synonym for *closed/suspended* that connotes a chance at redemption?

Comment: People are correct in saying that suspension is redeemable. If you want something that *sounds* gentler, though, you might say *on hold*.

Comment: In hockey, there is the "Penalty Box" where you are excluded from the game for a set period of time.  Maybe you could call your "mild suspension" something like "Penalty Box".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70061/1438) is what I think it is, you really ought to ask which *phrase* sounds gentler: "the question is closed" or "the question is suspended".  Neither sounds particularly kind to the person asking the question.  The first does carry a greater finality to my ear, however.

To answer the direct question, context is everything.  Pete Rose given a [lifetime suspension](http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/baseball/mlb/features/1999/pete_rose/part_1/) from baseball in 1989.  A criminal sometimes gets a [suspended sentence](http://definitions.uslegal.com/s/suspended-sentence/), which is gentler than serving hard time, but still a conviction.  Suspension in most social contexts, sounds like someone has done something very wrong.

As [Hellion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45209/what-is-a-gentler-word-than-suspended-or-closed/45211#45211) suggests, closed doors usually may be opened again.  A proposal may be closed for comments, which is usually final.  People sometimes say the ["book is closed"](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-of/close-the-book) on an incident to mean it has come to an end.  In social situations, "close" may be temporary or permanent depending on what rules are in force.

My suggestion for the particular problem of what to call a question that needs work in order to be open to new answers is (and was) "under construction".  Other suggestions that I like as both gentler and less final were "draft" and "needs work".

(You beat me to the idea of using this resource.  Great minds...)

Comment: "lifetime suspension" is just a euphemism.

Comment: Did this posting contribute to the "On Hold" change for newly closed questions?

Answer (score 4):

*suspended* should work for your purposes. This word indicates a temporary or conditional termination pending some future redeeming action.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I see nothing particularly final about a suspension, or even a closing; otherwise a door would be a single-use object, after which it would become a funny-colored part of the wall.

If something is terminated, then it is well and truly ended with no opportunity for redemption.  If something is only suspended, it can be resumed or reinstated with little effort.  You can further emphasize that by declaring it to be "temporarily suspended".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the context but would "deprecated" fit?

Answer (score 0):

Two words, but my single word finding skills seem to be ***[on hiatus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/On+hiatus)*** this morning. Perhaps that subsystem's ***[sabbatical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sabbatical)*** will end as more caffeine is consumed?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this non exhaustive list of synonyms for "suspended:"

> **adjourned**: suspended until a later slated time.

**tabled**: *US* : (of a bill, motion, etc.) laid aside for future discussion, or for an indefinite period of time.

> **on the table**: *US* : (of a bill, motion, etc.) laid aside for future discussion, or for an indefinite period of time.

**pigeonholed**: lay aside for the present; deferred.

> **on hold**: *Informal* : into a state of delay or indeterminate suspension.

**on the back burner**: *Fig.* : on hold or suspended temporarily.

> **frozen**: (of a process) suspended temporarily.